# How to change the home page of my Rails app to show Registration page instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing, rails-routing

I would like to make the homepage for an app (ie landing page) display a registration page. Unless the user is logged in - in which case they just find the "statuses" page.

Here are what I believe are the two relevant excerpts:

```
  as :user do
    get '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register    
    get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
    get '/logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end

[...]

resources :statuses
  get 'feed', to: 'statuses#index', as: :feed
  root to: 'statuses#index'
```

Basically, I'm trying to get these two pages to swap their routes and route names. Unless, as mentioned, if someone is already signed in, then the landing page is the statuses page.

I only know a bit about this sort of thing, such as "get," and the URL aspects. If anyone could provide guidance, I'd be much obliged.

Here's the routes.rb file:

```
Treebook::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :activities, only: [:index]

  as :user do
    get '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register    
    get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
    get '/logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end

  devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]

  as :user do
    get "/login" => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post "/login" => 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
    delete "/logout" => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end

  resources :user_friendships do
    member do
      put :accept
      put :block
    end
  end

  resources :statuses
  get 'feed', to: 'statuses#index', as: :feed
  root to: 'statuses#index'

  scope ":profile_name" do
    resources :albums do
      resources :pictures
    end
  end

  get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show', as: 'profile'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just send the user to the statuses page, and redirect all users who are not signed in to the sign in?

```
class StatusesController
  before_action :authorize!, only: :index

  def index
    #...
  end

  def authorize! # I believe this method is provided by devise
    unless signed_in?
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
root 'statuses#index'
```

Comment: Afaik it's `authenticate_user!`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'd still prefer the default page to be the sign up page though. Most sites do that, such as Fb, Twitter, etc. I tried the code provided and it still sets the localhost:3000 to statuses, as expected.

Comment: That's not true at all. If you go to twitter.com or facebook.com and you're signed in, you see your feed not the sign in page. You are not redirected to another page.